# mongodb edit array don't update it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to edit the collection of users where their purchase date has expired but when I'm saving, user.role have been updated but purchaseHistory don't have been updated.

Here is the function

```
async function checkExpiredPurchase() {
    const users = await User.find({
        "purchaseHistory.expdate": { $exists: true, $lte: new Date() }
    });
    for(const user of users) {
        let purchases = await user.purchaseHistory.map(purchase => {
            if(purchase.expdate && purchase.expdate <= new Date()) {
                purchase.expdate = null;
            }
            return purchase
        });
        user.role = "Utilisateur"
        user.purchaseHistory = purchases
        console.log(user.purchaseHistory) //here it return [{"date":"2022-12-12T20:53:48.467Z","item":"VIP","expdate":null,"methode":"PayPal"}] which is what I want
        user.save(function(err, resolve) {
            if (err)
                console.log('db error', err)
                // saved!
        });
    }
}
```

And when I check on MongoDB Compass (after refreshing ofc), I see that the role have been updated but not the array with purchaseHistory since expdate is still egal to a date and not to "null"

And I've also tried with this code for update

```
User.updateOne(
            { _id: user.id },
            { $set: { purchaseHistory: purchases }, $set: { role: "Utilisateur" } },
          ).then(() => { console.log('should be good')})
```

But as well as the other one, role update, not purchaseHistory

There was never an error in the console. Thank you in advance for any answers you can bring me

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the problem, it worked here just fine:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:password@0.0.0.0:50000", { dbName: "somedb" });

    const User = mongoose.model("user-test", {
        purchaseHistory: [{ expdate: Date, item: String }],
        role: String
    });

    await User.deleteMany({});

    await User.insertMany([
        { role: "User", purchaseHistory: [{ expdate: "1800-01-01", item: "VIP" }], },
        { role: "User 2", purchaseHistory: [{ expdate: "2050-01-01", item: "VIP" }], }
    ]);

    const users = await User.find({
        "purchaseHistory.expdate": { $exists: true, $lte: new Date() }
    });

    console.log("\r\nDOCUMENT BEFORE SAVE:\r\n\r\n", users[0]);

    for (const user of users) {
        user.purchaseHistory.forEach(purchase => {
            if (purchase.expdate && purchase.expdate <= new Date()) {
                purchase.expdate = null;
            }
        });
        user.role = "Utilisateur"

        console.log("\r\nDOCUMENT AFTER SAVE:\r\n\r\n", await user.save());
    }
})();
```